# Random bar graph in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, plot

Is it possible to generate a random bar graph in latex?

The only way to do this seems to be using the tikz package.

Is there any code for this

Thanks and regards

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 4):

You weren't exactly very specific about what you're after, so I probably shouldn't post this in the first place, but:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar]
\addplot+[samples at={0,...,10}]{rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can i have some more examples

Comment: @DeltaScuti_Fomalhautb Not without you specifying in detail what you're after, no.

Comment: I want a randomly generated graph which can a bar graph or pie graph etc. The graph has to be plotted randomly and it should be center aligned

Comment: @DeltaScuti_Fomalhautb That was just as vague as your initial question. Look in chapter 4.5 in [the `pgfplots` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf) for the different types of plots `pgfplots` provides. It can't do pie charts though, for that you'll need to use a different package, for example `pgf-pie`. Centering a plot like the above is no different to centering something like an image. So for example add `\begin{center}` before `\begin{tikzpicture}`, and add `\end{center}` after `\end{tikzpicture}`.