# Beautiful random graphs

Tags: graphs, big-list

Are their any examples of beautiful random graphs like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar]
\addplot+[samples at={0,...,10}]{rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to form a collection of such graphs so please post a lot.

Graph means a graph which plots a random data each time I compile it.

Comment: »I would like to form a collection«  This site is for questions and answers.

Comment: @henrimenke us their a existing collection of such graphs and my question is not a duplicate.

Comment: @HenriMenke Why do we have `big-list` questions, then?

Comment: @cfr I don't know and I don't like them either.  They do not comply with the format of this site.

Comment: List-type questions are, however, generally something like by-community-consensus, generally community wiki and open to link-only answers. If that's what you want, I suggest making your question community wiki, adding the list tag and being clear that you are on a gathering mission. But people may not see the need for a list of these. They aren't generally intended as collections for individuals, but more as something like communal resources. At least, that has been my impression/understanding. They are certainly not standard SE types.

Comment: @DeltaScuti_Fomalhautb If it's not a duplicate then it's off-topic.  You choose.

Comment: Sorry, I indeed meant `big-list`. `lists` is for `itemize`, `enumerate` and other `list` environments. What's the point of this? What use is such a collection? What would somebody want it for? It seems purposeless to me: like collecting old bee hives, with no intention of keeping bees.

Comment: @cfr I just want them to see the beauty of pgfplots

Comment: Did you check the manual? Or pgfplots.net?

Comment: You want a collection of the different types of diagrams pgfplots can produce (scatter, bar, pie etc.) without caring what the diagrams represent specifically. I.e. random means where the data comes from (aviation, farming crops, weather statistics, crime rates). Is *that* what you are looking for?

Comment: @Johannes_B yep you got my point

Comment: pgfplots.net seems to be down at the moment, but this is what you are looking for.

Comment: http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/ is back up again.

Comment: @Johannes_B There are only 2 random graphs on pgfplots.net/tikz/examples

Comment: What the hell is a random graph? Do you mean graph as graph? Or do you mean diagram?

Comment: Please edit the question and explain what you mean by graph.

Comment: The `rnd` function will change its output every minute (the seed depends on the time), so if you compile ten times while the clock shows 19:20, you'll get the same output every time, but when the clock turns to 19:21 you get new output. Beyond that, I don't think a long list of examples of every type of plot `pgfplots` can make is all that useful, just look in the manual as I mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/400907/, and if there's a specific type of plot you can't get to work, ask about that.